# launch sbpl_lattice_planner (hydro ) errors

Tags: ros, sbpl-lattice-planner, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all.

i 'm using  ubuntu 12.04  ,turtlebot1 and hydro,created  a catkin_ws workspace , installed  sbpl  through  `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-sbpl`thanks to Johannes https://github.com/meyerj/sbpl_lattice_planner and ahendrix https://github.com/trainman419/sbpl_lattice_planner , i download  Johannes's and `catkin_make`successfuly,but when i

```
roslaunch sbpl_lattice_planner  move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch
```

it came out two errors,`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [stage/stageros]: can't locate node [stageros] in package [stage]` ,`ERROR: cannot launch node of type [nav_view/nav_view]: nav_view` . when i `rospack`  find stage and stage_ros in the path`'/opt/ros/hydro/share/'`

my questions are:

1. in the move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch,how to correct  the line  `<node pkg="stage" type="stageros" name="stageros" args="$(find sbpl_lattice_planner)/worlds/willow.world" respawn="false" >`to  fix  the   first error?
2. in the sbpl_lattice_planner/launch/move_base/nav_view_sbpl.xml,how to correct  the line `node name="nav_view" pkg="nav_view" type="nav_view" respawn="false">`to fix the  second error(i want to use rviz to  replace nav_view,but don't know how to do ),does the `'remap  from ...to ...'`lines also need to  be changed ?
3. in the sbpl_lattice_planner/launch/move_base/move_base/move_base_sbpl.xml, does the line `<param name="SBPLLatticePlanner/primitive_filename" value="$(find sbpl)/matlab/mprim/pr2.mprim"/>` fit my turtlebot1 (it can only  forward ,backward and  rotation)?

thanks to your  time and suggestions !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193166/launch--sbpl_lattice_planner-(hydro-)-errors/) by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2014-09-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Background: it looks like the launch file is running a simulator. You'll probably need to adjust it a lot to run it on a real robot.

1. is trying to start the stage simulator. You should be able to install it with `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-stage`
2. is trying to start nav_view. You should probably just remove that node and run rivz manually instead.
3. Once you're comfortable running the sbpl planner in simulation, you should generate a new set of motion primitives to fit your turtlebot (or find a similar project and use their motion primitives).

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-09-22**:
@ahendrix,thanks . i removed that nav_view node ,`sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-stage`,and then only roslaunch the move_base_sbpl_fake_localization_2.5cm.launch,the first error still occur .in `'/opt/ros/hydro/share/'`,there are only stage and stage_ros,not exist stageros.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-22**:
It looks like the package for stage is now `stage_ros` and the node name is still `stageros`

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-09-22**:
corrected  the package name, and launch again , occured the error like [link](http://answers.ros.org/question/58948/stage-tutorial-error-laser-model-type-not-found/), there is a patch[link](https://github.com/ros-gbp/stage-release/tree/patches/debian/hydro/precise/stage),did you know how to use it

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-22**:
It looks like the simulation needs to be updated for the new version of stage. I suspect no one has run that simulation in a long, long time; you may just want to abandon it and move to a turtlebot simulation or a real robot.

**Comment by [jxl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5454/jxl/) on 2014-09-23**:
ok, sir, i will try the planner on the turtlebot .thanks a lot !!